# Wcf Backward compatibility issue - missing namespace on method parameter

Tags: wcf, soap, basichttpbinding

we are hosted our WCF web service in windows service. We are using basicHttpBinding. We need preserve backward compatibility with Soap 1.1 Web service. Our problem is missing namespace on element **EPTalkMessage** in web method parameter. I searched a lot but I didn't find some way to add namespace to this element.

Soap from old web service is:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://aaa.sk/EPTalk/IssueDocument</Action>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<IssueDocument xmlns="http://aaa.sk/EPTalk">
  <EPTalkMessage xmlns="http://aaa.sk/EPTalk/ToSignInput" />
</IssueDocument>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

New generated soap is:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://aaa.sk/EPTalk/IssueDocument</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <IssueDocument xmlns="http://aaa.sk/EPTalk">
      <EPTalkMessage />
    </IssueDocument >
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Service signature is as follows:

```
[ServiceContract (Namespace = "http://aaa.sk/EPTalk")]
[XmlSerializerFormat(Use = OperationFormatUse.Literal, Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document)]
public interface IRegistryInputWebService
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "http://aaa.sk/EPTalk/IssueDocument")]
    RegistryServiceResult IssueDocument([MessageParameter(Name = "EPTalkMessage")]
        UpvsPortalEmulator.ToSignInput.EPTalkMessage message);
}
```

Binding:

```
BasicHttpBinding
{                   
 MaxReceivedMessageSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10,
 MaxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10,
 ReaderQuotas =
              {
                MaxArrayLength = 1024 * 1024 * 10,
                MaxStringContentLength = 1024 * 1024 * 10
               },
 MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text,
 Security = new BasicHttpSecurity
                {
                 Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None
                 }
 };
```

Edited: EPTalkMessage definition added.

```
 [XmlType, XmlRoot (ElementName = "EPTalkMessage", Namespace = Declarations.SchemaVersion, IsNullable = false), Serializable]
    public class EPTalkMessage
{
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while, I resolved this issue with MessageContracts.